# Why isn't `std::compare_three_way` a `std::strict_weak_order`?

Tags: c++, c++20

With C++20 concepts and three-way-comparison, I have made my own `Map` like this:

```
template<
    typename TKey,
    typename TValue,
    std::strict_weak_order<TKey, TKey> KeyComparer = std::compare_three_way, // Error: template constraint not satisfied
    typename PairAllocator = std::allocator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
>class SortedMap
```

When `SortedMap` initializes, it failed with error `template constraint not satisfied`.

Modify `std::strict_weak_order` to `typename` then it's ok. (Error comes here certainly.)

---

Why doesn't `std::compare_three_way` satisfy `std::strict_weak_order`?

Comment: A strict weak order is a binary relation. A binary relation is a predicate (boolean function) on a set of pairs. `std::compare_three_way` is not a predicate, it is a function object that returns a `class std::weak_ordering`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::strict_weak_order<R, T, U>` requires `R` to be a predicate - that invoking `R` on objects of types `T` and `U` gives you `bool`. But `std::compare_three_way` does not return `bool`, it returns one of the comparison categories that are the result of `<=>` (e.g. `std::strong_ordering`).

There is currently no concept in the standard library for if something is an invocable that returns a comparison category (in the same way that `strict_weak_order` is the the concept generalization of using `<`).

So either:

1. You build your map on top of three-way comparisons and do everything accordingly. This means writing your own concept for a three-way comparing object. Something like this would do:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Cat>
concept compares_as = std::same_as<std::common_comparison_category_t<T, Cat>, Cat>;

template <typename R, typename T, typename U>
concept three_way_order = std::regular_invocable<R, T, U>
  && compares_as<std::invoke_result_t<R, T, U>, std::weak_ordering>;
```

This would reject partial orders - which means you can't have `double` as a key (or rather couldn't use `<=>` as the comparison directly, users would have to provide a custom comparison function to reject NaNs or some such). If you want to to handle partial orders in your container directly, change `std::weak_ordering` to `std::partial_ordering` above.

Or

2. You build your map on top of `<` as `std::map` does, and so you would use `std::less<>` or `std::less<Key>` as your default comparison type. Since `x < y` can rewrite to `(x <=> y) < 0` anyway, this would still use `<=>` if that is the way that `<` is implemented. But in your container implementation, you would just get a two-way comparison result (i.e. `bool`) instead of a three-way comparison result (e.g. `std::strong_ordering`).